# jquery ui sortable temporary element swapping during drag

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, swap

I need to implement temporary drag replacement in a size-limited jquery ui sortable list.

I have 2 sortable lists:

- A "slot" with only 1 spot to hold a single element
- A "bucket" that holds several elements from which the user can pick any to fill the "slot"

The user has to drag an element from the bucket into the slot. While the user is holding the element  with the mouse over the slot, **if the slot is already occupied**, the current slotted element should be moved into the bucket to visually make room for the dragged element. Then the user has 2 options:

- If the user drops the new element: insert the new element into the slot
- If the user cancels the drop: move the previously slotted element back into the slot (as it was originally)

This behaviour should repeat until the user has either cancelled the drag or dropped the element into the slot or the bucket.

To visually limit the slot to a single element, I have limited it to the exact height of a single element and setted its overflow to hidden.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to produce the effect while keeping a single element in the slot at all time.

EDIT 1: [Here is an example of what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/uUSJG/)

```
$(".slot").bind("sortchange", function (event, ui) {
    var slot = $(event.target);
    var bucket = $(".bucket");

    // Move any element already in the slot (other than the currently
    // dragged element) into the bucket
    var slotElements = slot.children(".item").not(ui.item);
    if (slotElements.length > 0) {
        for (var idx = 0; idx < slotElements.length; idx += 1) {
            var element = $(slotElements[idx]);
            moveAnimate(element, bucket);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any code? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I have tried but the problem is that the dragged element remains "attached" to the slot until it is dragged back over the bucket, forcing the element to also go into the slot when the user releases the mouse.